# Issues with clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a simple navigation with sub-navigation drop-downs. The desired functionality is for the drop-down to hide itself after a certain amount of seconds if it has not been entered by the mouse. Though if it is currently hovered, I would like to clearTimeout so that it does not hide while the mouse is inside of it.

```
    function hideNav() {
        $('.subnav').hover(function(){
            clearTimeout(t);
        }, function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
}

$('#nav li').mouseover(function() {
    t = setTimeout(function() { $('.active').hide()}, 4000);
    //var liTarget = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.active').hide();
    $('.subnav', this).show().addClass('active');
    navTimer;
    hideNav();
});
```

What am I missing? Am I passing the handle wrong?

Comment: And what exactly is the issue?

Comment: maybe your scope of the timer variable isnt right? Does it exist? Try like this: window.timer = setTimeout .... and clearTimeout(window.timer)

Comment: What @MichaelKoper said -- you need to explicitly make `t` a global variable. Right now it's local to your anonymous mouseover function.

Comment: The issue is that it's not clearing the timeout. I did change the script to define t outside of the function but it's still not working.

Comment: @mblase75: Omitting the `var` will make it an implicit global.

Comment: There was no `var` originally and the clearTimeout still didn't work. Am I missing something required to clear the original function?

Answer (score 0):

You should also clear the timeout in mouseover, before setting the new timeout.
Otherwise a timeout started before will still be active, but no longer accessible via the t-variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the timer variable global.

```
function hideNav() {
  $('.subnav').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(window.t);
  }
}

$('#nav li').mouseover(function() {
  window.t = setTimeout(function() { $('.active').hide()}, 4000);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing it the recommended way (JS statement as a string):

```
t = setTimeout("$('.active').hide()", 4000);
```

Comment: That uses `eval` which is frowned upon.

Comment: That's good to know. W3C doesn't provide any function() examples, so I assumed it was the preferred way. I suppose I'll take a 'downvote' for the sake of learning something new. ;-)